# GetMultiple for Mints?

Tags: web3.js, spl-token, mint, typescript

Let's say we have an array of Pubkeys: `let arr: Pubkey[] = [whatever]`

We have `connection.getMultipleAccountsInfo(arr)` to get many AccountInfo in one RPC call.

We have `getMint()` from the spl-token library to return a Mint.

Is there a getMultiple equivalent for mints? Should we use `getMultipleAccountsInfo` and parse the accountInfo to a Mint?

Answer (score 2):

Posting the answer with parsed accounts here for reference:

```
    let mintInfos = await connection.getMultipleAccountsInfo(mintKeys);
    for (let i = 0; i < mintInfos.length; i++) {
      let mint: RawMint = MintLayout.decode(mintInfos[i].data);
    }
```